# R not running on command prompt and Anaconda prompt

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have downloaded R and command prompt is not reading it. When I write R in prompt (anaconda or command) it says R is not recognized as an internal or external command. What do I do, i need to run it in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Apparently R isn't in your path. That's what you need to correct

Comment: And just to make sure... You did install R right?

Comment: @Dason yes I installed R and Rstudio